# Why using ref() in Vue3 causes "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm kinda new to Vue3 and encountered such problem in one project. Below are my pseudo code blocks:

nested variable declaration:

```
const testData = ref([
    {
      type: '',
      title: '',
      data: {
        labels: [] as string[],
        datasets: [
          {
            type: '',
            label: '',
            data: [] as number[],
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  ])
```

and here is  where the error thrown

```
 GetData().then(response=>{
    if(response != undefined){
            response.result.forEach(value=>{
              testData.value[0].data.datasets[0].data.push(value)//this line throws out the error 
            })
    }
         ...  
 }).catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

and the error message lies below:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at Array.value (helpers.segment.js:1550:26)
at Array.instrumentations.<computed> (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:398:42)
at Array.value (helpers.segment.js:1550:26)
at Array.instrumentations.<computed> (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:398:42)
at Array.value (helpers.segment.js:1550:26)
at Array.instrumentations.<computed> (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:398:42)
at Array.value (helpers.segment.js:1550:26)
at Array.instrumentations.<computed> (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:398:42)
at Array.value (helpers.segment.js:1550:26)
at Array.instrumentations.<computed> (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:398:42)
```

According to other online articles, they all said this error happens because the loop, but here the foreach loop only has to loop less than 15 times, and once I changed the testData into a plain array without using ref(), everything just worked fine and the final result got rendered as what I was expecting. Can somebody just tell me the reason?

Comment: It could happen because somewhere in your code a change to a ref trigger a change to another ref, which loops back to change the first ref.. Basically, you have an infinite loop somewhere.

Comment: thanks for your reply, here the testData is pretty self-contained, it has no interaction with other ref()s, I juts intended to fill it with data grabbed from backend and pass it to the childcompoent to get it rendered on charts.

Comment: I don't see how that code can crash, you made the root variable reactive with a `ref(..)`, but not the whole object, and pushing inside the object won't trigger reactivity. If you want the whole object to be reactive, you can use `reactive(..)` instead. My guess is the issue is somewhere else from what you're showing us.

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. It could at least be improved with `.push(...response.result)`

Comment: @Guillaume F. thanks for your insight! that page I was working on is pretty clean, but when I looked into one nested child component, there's one computed property doing mapping on that data I was passing through to it

Comment: @DJyang can you maybe elaborate a bit more and submit an answer to your own question with what exactly you changed to make it working? I have exactly the same issue currently.